# Hide WooCommerce My Account Orders if the total purchased amount equal 0

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In woocommerce, I am trying to hide the orders if there total is 0.
Here is my code, but it does not work. Any idea about the problem?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 
'hide_zero_total_orders_from_my_account', 10, 1 );
function hide_zero_total_orders_from_my_account( $args ) {
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'     => '_order_total',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
);
return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead a lightweight SQL query to get customer total purchases and use that query to hide My account Orders section if the total purchases amount is equal to 0 (zero):

```php
// Get customer purchases total amount
function get_customer_purchases_total_amount(){
    global $wpdb;

    return (float) $$wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-processing','wc-completed')
        AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total'
        AND pm2.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm2.meta_value = %d
    ", get_current_user_id() ) );
}

// Hide My account Orders section conditionally
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'hide_customer_account_orders_conditionally', 100, 1 );
function hide_customer_account_orders_conditionally( $items ) {
    if ( get_customer_purchases_total_amount() == 0 ) {
        unset( $items['orders'] );
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.